# Copy data from a file to a datastorage

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Is it possible to export to insert queries?

I have a doubt, In the page (http://www.filehelpers.net/) in the image "Advance uses of the library: Copy data from a file to a datastorage" but I can not find the information and know if I can export to sql.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. You didn't put any code in and you add a link to a third-party website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class CustomersVerticalBar
{
    public string CustomerID;
    public string CompanyName;
    public string ContactName;
    public string ContactTitle;
    public string Address;
    public string City;
    public string Country;
}

class Program
{
    private static string GetInsertSqlCust(object record)
    {
        CustomersVerticalBar obj = (CustomersVerticalBar)record;

        return String.Format("INSERT INTO Customers (Address, City, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, Country, CustomerID) " +
                " VALUES ( '{0}' , '{1}' , '{2}' , '{3}' , '{4}' , '{5}' , '{6}'  ); ",
                obj.Address,
                obj.City,
                obj.CompanyName,
                obj.ContactName,
                obj.ContactTitle,
                obj.Country,
                obj.CustomerID
            );
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlServerStorage storage = new SqlServerStorage(typeof(CustomersVerticalBar));

        storage.ServerName = "MYSERVER";
        storage.DatabaseName = "Northwind";

        // Comment this for Windows Auth
        storage.UserName = "shamp00";
        storage.UserPass = "whatever";

        storage.InsertSqlCallback = new InsertSqlHandler(GetInsertSqlCust);

        storage.InsertRecords(CommonEngine.ReadFile(typeof(CustomersVerticalBar), "infile.txt"));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I'm sure there used to be some docs for this - they seem to be missing from the latest website. You can look at the unit tests in the FileHelpers source code for [some more examples](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/blob/master/FileHelpers.Tests/Tests/DataLink/SqlServerStorage.cs).